# Why can I multiply a string in JavaScript, but not add it?

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

For my BMI calculator, I take user input from several input fields. I expect the value of imperialHeight to be 65 after the calculation, but it actually is 605.

```
// user input through input field with id imperialHeightFt = 5
// user input through input field with id imperialHeightIn = 5

let imperialHeight = (imperialHeightFt.value * 12) + imperialHeightIn.value;
```

Apparently, JavaScript does something like this:

5 * 12 = 60

'60' + '5' = '605'

After some research, I get that .value returns a string. It seems that JavaScript treats the string as a number anyway if I multiply it. This code returns 65, as expected.

```
let imperialHeight = (imperialHeightFt.value * 12) + (imperialHeightIn.value * 1);
```

My code works like this, but I'd like to know what happens here. Why can I use the string returned by .value to multiply, but not to add?

Comment: In javascript + is used for both math adding and string concatenation. If a value is of type string, javascript assumes you are appending the strings together. Just convert both with something like parseInt(value) or parseFloat(value)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `+` operator performs string concatenation when at least one operand is a string, whereas the `*` and other math operators attempt to convert each operand to a number.

Comment: I must remember that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you get your data through [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) element, and by default, the [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#value) attribute (what the user writes) is always `string`.

And in JavaScript, multiplying and adding strings will always result in a string therefore use [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/Number) to convert your data to numbers.

```js
let imperialHeightFt = document.getElementById("imperialHeightFt");
let imperialHeightIn = document.getElementById("imperialHeightIn");

let imperialHeight = Number(imperialHeightFt.value) * 12 + Number(imperialHeightIn.value);
console.log(imperialHeight);
```

```html
<input id="imperialHeightFt" value="5" />
<input id="imperialHeightIn" value="5" />
```

Comment: That is a better way to convert strings to numbers than multiplying by 1. Thanks!

Comment: @Marjolein You're welcome. Always ready to help :-)